# Pausing Webkit Animation Across Multiple Classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am having trouble pausing multiple animations on hover.

I have included the pertinent parts of the code below (Not the entire thing because it is too long).  The main 2 animations for the piece are in the .orbit and .pos classes.  When I apply the animation play state property it only pauses the animations in the .orbit class (orbit) and not the animations in the .pos class (invert).

How can I get everything to pause on hover?

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge;chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable = no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<title dir="ltr">WK 3D CSS Solar System</title>



<style>

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300);

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }


  article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block; }

body {
  line-height: 1; }

ol, ul {
  list-style: none; }

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none; }

blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
  content: none; }

table {

  -moz-border-collapse: collapse;
  -webkit-border-collapse: collapse;
  -o-border-collapse: collapse;
  -ms-border-collapse: collapse;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  -moz-border-spacing: 0; 
  -webkit-border-spacing: 0; 
  -o-border-spacing: 0; 
  -ms-border-spacing: 0; 
  border-spacing: 0; }



  * {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box; 
  box-sizing: border-box; }


  body {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  width: 1500px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: transparent; 
  }


  #universe  {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center 40%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover; }



#mercury:hover, #venus:hover, #jupiter:hover, #saturn:hover, #uranus:hover   {
-moz-animation-play-state: paused; 
-webkit-animation-play-state: paused; 
-o-animation-play-state: paused;
-ms-animation-play-state: paused;
 animation-play-state: paused; 
}

  #galaxy {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /*perspective: 4000;*/ }

  #solar-system {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
  transform-style: preserve-3d;  }

  .orbit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 37%;
  left: 48%;
  border: 0px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);

  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-animation-name: orbit;
  -webkit-animation-name: orbit;
  -o-animation-name: orbit;
  -ms-animation-name: orbit;
  animation-name: orbit;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear; 
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; 
  -o-animation-timing-function: linear; 
  -ms-animation-timing-function: linear; 
  animation-timing-function: linear; }



  .orbit .orbit {
  -moz-animation-name: suborbit; 
  -webkit-animation-name: suborbit; 
  -o-animation-name: suborbit; 
  -ms-animation-name: suborbit; 
  animation-name: suborbit; }

  .pos {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 6em;
  height: 6em;
  margin-top: -1em;
  margin-left: -1em;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-animation-name: invert;
  -webkit-animation-name: invert;
  -o-animation-name: invert;
  -ms-animation-name: invert;
  animation-name: invert;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear; 
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; 
  -o-animation-timing-function: linear; 
  -ms-animation-timing-function: linear; 
  animation-timing-function: linear;   }

  #sun{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 220px;
  height: 219px;
  margin-top: -120px;
  margin-left: -120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;  }

  .planet {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
  margin-left: -0.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
   -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;  }

  #earth .moon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
  margin-left: -0.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;  }

  #sun {
  background-color: rgba(153, 211, 237, 0.4);
  background-image:url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/236154657/Popup_Circle_New3.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position:center; 
  background-size: cover;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 60px rgba(153, 211, 237, 0.4);  
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 60px rgba(153, 211, 237, 0.4);  
  -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 60px rgba(153, 211, 237, 0.4);  
  -ms-box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 60px rgba(153, 211, 237, 0.4);  
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 60px rgba(153, 211, 237, 0.4);  }

  .planet {
  background-color: #202020;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;  }

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------- animations */

@-webkit-keyframes orbit {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg); }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-360deg); } }

@-moz-keyframes orbit {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotateZ(0deg); }

  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotateZ(-360deg); } }

@keyframes orbit {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg); }

  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(-360deg); } }



@-webkit-keyframes suborbit {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateZ(0deg); }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateZ(-360deg); } }

@-moz-keyframes suborbit {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateZ(0deg); }

  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateZ(-360deg); } }

@keyframes suborbit {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateZ(0deg); }

  100% {
    transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateZ(-360deg); } }



@-webkit-keyframes invert {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(0deg); }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg); } }

@-moz-keyframes invert {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(0deg); }

  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg); } }

@keyframes invert {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(0deg); }

  100% {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg); } }

</style>

</head>

<body class="opening hide-UI view-3D zoom-large data-open controls-close">

    <div id="universe" class="scale-stretched">
      <div id="galaxy">

        <div id="solar-system" class="Mercury">

          <div id="venus" class="orbit">
            <div class="pos">
              <div class="planet">
                <dl class="infos">
                  <dt></dt>
                  <dd><span></span></dd>
                </dl>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="earth" class="orbit">
            <div class="pos">
              <div class="orbit">
                <div class="pos">
                  <div class="moon"></div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="planet">
                <dl class="infos">
                  <dt>test</dt>
                  <dd><span></span></dd>
                </dl>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="mars" class="orbit">
            <div class="pos">
              <div class="planet">
                <dl class="infos">
                  <dt>Mars</dt>
                  <dd><span></span></dd>
                </dl>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="jupiter" class="orbit">
            <div class="pos">
              <div class="planet">
                <dl class="infos">
                  <dt></dt>
                  <dd><span></span></dd>
                </dl>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="saturn" class="orbit">
            <div class="pos">
              <div class="planet">
                <dl class="infos">
                  <dt></dt>
                  <dd><span></span></dd>
                </dl>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

           <div id="uranus" class="orbit">
            <div class="pos">
              <div class="planet">
                <dl class="infos">
                  <dt></dt>
                  <dd><span></span></dd>
                </dl>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

           <div id="neptune" class="orbit">
            <div class="pos">
              <div class="planet">
                <dl class="infos">
                  <dt>Neptune</dt>
                  <dd><span></span></dd>
                </dl>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

           <div id="mercury" class="orbit">
            <div class="pos">
              <div class="planet">
                <dl class="infos">
                  <dt></dt>
                  <dd><span></span></dd>
                </dl>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div id="sun">
            <dl class="infos">
              <dt>Sun</dt>
              <dd><span></span></dd>
            </dl>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') { 
      document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='http://secure.cart32.com/WarrenKahn/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    }
    </script>
    <script src="http://secure.cart32.com/WarrenKahn/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://secure.cart32.com/WarrenKahn/scripts.min.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No opposed to JavaScript at all.  It just isn't my strong suit.

Comment: Can you provide a working sample or jsFiddle? Your code is not animating / functioning on my local test server. You seem to have lots of extraneous code for this simplified sample animation.